# Browsing to a link to a hidden comment does not properly expand that comment

Tags: bug

### Defect Description

When the user copy/pastes a URL to a specific comment into their address bar (or clicks on a link pasted into some post or answer or comment inside SE), and that comment is hidden, the web page does not expand it (unhide it) so that it can be seen. Consequence: The user is baffled and then concludes that the link is a link rot, which is not the case.

### Steps to reproduce:

Click on [How can I edit the beginning of the counsel-find-file filename whilst preserving the rest](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63010/how-can-i-edit-the-beginning-of-the-counsel-find-file-filename-whilst-preserving)

Notice that your browser does not display that comment:

[image]

Then click on that **Show 1 more comment** link.  Then you are able to see it:

[image]